Elementor grid background - How to remove it?
I'm struggeling with my website, where i have this "grid background" (see picture).
I'm using Elementor, and i can't find any option to remove this grid.
Any suggestion ?
Thank you all
I dived into the configuration system on wordpress backend... can't see any options :-(
Screenshot of the background grid
